# Getting error while importing file from a different folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I am trying to build a webpage using django. Following is my project structure:

`Project 
    |- src 
       |- __init__.py
       |- algorithm 
          |- checker.py 
    |- website 
         |- website
            |- __init__.py
            |- websiteapp
                |- views.py`

In my views.py I want to call a function which is inside src/checker.py.
To do that I wrote `from src.algorithm.checker import *`.
But this is giving me the following error:
`from src.algorithm.checker import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`. How to import this file in views.py?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: You probably need to add __init__.py in algorithm and websiteapp folder as well.